# I would like to change the size of my partitions (increase Windows 7 by approx 50gb)

Tags: 11.10, windows, partitioning

So I have installed 11.10 alongside windows7, and I didn't realise that I needed more than I allocated for Windows 7 to back up my iPod. Is there a simple way to do this? I tried to reinstall, but it didn't allow me to change partition sizes. Can I erase all and start again or will that actually completely erase my windows installation?

Cheers

Comment: Backup your data to another disk before you resize anything, it doesn't always go smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You should boot up with the Ubuntu BootCD and use Gparted to resize your Ubuntu partition. When finished, boot into Windows and use the Disk Manager to resize your Windows partition.